# invalid factor level data.frame error inspite of stringsAsFactors=FALSE

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I have factor level problem. I thought it would be solved with stringAsFactors=FALSE, but it's not working.

here `pL` is a list with 290 elements.
I would like to define an empty data.frame, than fill it using `rbind`.

```
ttable <- data.frame(ID_REF=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), IDENTIFIER=c("ERN2", "HTR5A", "ACPP", "GNAO1", "HTR1F", "DNAH1"), GSM11708=c("<NA>", 1.994, "<NA>","<NA>","<NA>","<NA>"), GSM11735=c(0.18, "<NA>","<NA>","<NA>","<NA>","<NA>"))
pL <- list("GSTT4", "AHRR", "HAX1", "DNM1L", "MEIS1", "SLC17A3", "CES2", "MLL2", "IKBKB", "GSTA4")

gn <- data.frame(gn = character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in pL){
  n <- nrow(subset(ttable, IDENTIFIER==i))
  if (n < 1){
    gn <- rbind(gn, i)
  }
  else{
    for(j in 1:n){
      gn <- rbind(gn, i)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Without data we can't reproduce your error. You should also avoid using `rbind` inside a loop.

Comment: You could try `rbind(gb, i, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` or set the global option. However, @agstudy gave very relevant advice. Growing an object in a loop is slooooowwww.

Comment: @agstudy Could you write too please, what else should I use?

Comment: you final gn is just a vector of index?

Comment: @Roland What else than loop can i use, when I have a list, and I should search the items of the list in a special data.frame object (from the biological GEO database)?

Comment: My final gn is a dataframe, with one column (with column name), it will be a column in a bigger table (with cbind).

Comment: Well, usually you would use `lapply` and relatives. Give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) and there is a good chance that someone will show you how.

Comment: I add an reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to help without a reproducible example. But this should work:

```
gn1 <- unlist(lapply(pL,function(i){
  n <- nrow(subset(ttable, IDENTIFIER==i))
  gn <- if (n < 1) i  else seq(n)
}))
```

z I run your code I get `gn` data.frame. You run mine you get `gn1` vector. I `cbind` the 2 for comparison.

```
    cbind(as.data.frame(gn1),gn)
       gn1 X.GSTT4.
1    GSTT4    GSTT4
2     AHRR     AHRR
3     HAX1     HAX1
4    DNM1L    DNM1L
5    MEIS1    MEIS1
6  SLC17A3  SLC17A3
7     CES2     CES2
8     MLL2     MLL2
9    IKBKB    IKBKB
10   GSTA4    GSTA4
```

As you seed the 2 columns are identical.

Comment: I don't understand why 'gn' and not 'gn1'.

Comment: I meant in the first code third row. Why is or must be difference? Is better to use different variable names?

Comment: No need to be the same. It is local variable will be deleted once the function finish running.